# How to get a track of server side updates client side?

Tags: java, javascript, push-notification

The scenario is that I am having a piece of code written in Javascript that keeps refreshing after a short interval of time and keep matching with a file on the server side and if there is a change in the file on the server side it downloads the updated file. But because it keep refreshing all the time so it may create a huge traffic on the server on later run.

So i want to know that is there any kind of mechanism here (like push notifications i have heard though not sure about it) that can give a notification to the client when the file on the server side updates? So that client side may be free from creating unnecessary requests.

Given that my server side code is written in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider researching [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets) and [Server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events). I have not used any of them with Java but I'm sure that you can find a nice library.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am digging more in to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is websockets. These enable two way communication between a server and a (web) client. This way, you can send the push notifications to your client.

There is some more information [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) about websockets (the client side) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm) is the java documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i am digging more in to it.